# Как преобразовать строку в дату

Tags: c#, datetime

Есть строка `9.28.17 13:35`. Пытался несколькими способами привести его к `DateTime` - не получается

```
var dataopen = "9.28.17 13:35";
DateTime dateTime2;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dataopen, out dateTime2))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь перегрузкой [DateTime.TryParse, принимающей сведения о культуре и о стиле](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime.TryParse(dataopen, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
                  DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime2)
```

[Тестить!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrXtuu)

Answer (score 5):

Т.к у вас нестандартный формат даты, то пользуйтесь [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) и провайдите свой формат даты:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dataopen, "M.dd.yy HH:mm", null);
```

[Тестить!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/foISnH)